# secant line too long, trying not to use y limits

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use python to teach myself the basics of calc.

I am using matplotlib pyplot to trace a function curve and then draw a secant line from two points I specify (p1 & p2).

I think I have most of the math working ok but if I dont use limits (Y.min,Y.max of curve) on my Y axis then the secant line can sometimes get really long and "crush" my curve.

I'm just not sure what would be the best mathematical approach to limiting the line so it doesn't overshoot the curve's max or min y values:

No Limits Set:
[image: No Y Limit]

Limits Set to (Y.min,Y.max) of curve:
[image: With Y Limit Set To Y.min,Y.max of curve]

Heres my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ls = np.linspace(-2,2,100)
p1 = 2  #starts from zero
p2 = 50 #starts from zero

def draw_func(ls):
    x = ls
    y = x**2
    #y = (x**4-2*x**2+x)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    return y

x = ls
y = draw_func(ls)

x1 = x[p1]
x2 = x[p2]
y1 = y[p1]
y2 = y[p2]

m = (y2-y1) / (x2-x1)

delta_x = x2 - x1
delta_x = x1 + (delta_x/2)

b = y2 - y1
b = y1 + (b/2)

def draw_line(ls, m, b):
    x = ls
    y = (m * (x-delta_x)) + b
    plt.plot(x,y)

draw_line(ls, m, b)

plt.ylim(y.min(),y.max()) #This Is What I Was Hoping To Avoid

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different approaches you could take.

One is to only plot a portion of your secant line.  You can either evaluate it everywhere and filter out points much greater or less than your "main" curve or you can calculate a more limited range to evaluate it over.

The other is to tell matplotlib to only autoscale for the "main" curve and leave the limits alone for the other curve.

---

First off, I'll write your example slightly differently.  There's nothing wrong with the way you're doing things, but I find this style a bit more readable:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def main():
    x = np.linspace(-2,2,100)
    p1 = 2  #starts from zero
    p2 = 50 #starts from zero

    y1 = main_func(x)
    y2 = calculate_secant(x, y1, p1, p2)
    plot(x, y1, y2)
    plt.show()

def main_func(x):
    return x**2

def calculate_secant(x, y, p1, p2):
    points = [p1, p2]
    m, b = np.polyfit(x[points], y[points], 1)
    return m * x + b

def plot(x, y1, y2):
    plt.plot(x, y1)
    plt.plot(x, y2)

main()
```

And we'll get a "zoomed out" plot, which you don't want:

[image]

---

If we change the `plot` function slightly, we can tell matplotlib not to change the axes limits when plotting the second line:

```
def plot(x, y1, y2):
    plt.plot(x, y1)
    plt.plot(x, y2, scalex=False, scaley=False)
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, we could mask out points from the green line that are significantly greater than the blue line (the key is the third line below, the others are identical and given for context:

```
y1 = main_func(x)
y2 = calculate_secant(x, y1, p1, p2)
y2[y2 < y1] = np.nan
plot(x, y1, y2)
```

This will have the (possibly unwanted, possible desired) side effect of clipping off the left hand side where the two lines cross as well:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the coordinates of the curve's apex.  Draw the line from the start to that x value, instead of continuing through the entire range.